# PyWin32: Windows Classic theme

Tags: python, windows, windows-vista, python-3.x, pywin32

In the PyWin32 demos folder, the **win32gui_dialog.py** sample uses the *classic windows*  controls.
Can the **Windows Vista** themed buttons also be displayed using PyWin32, and if so, how? I'm using ActivePython 3.1, if that makes any difference.

Sample:

[PyWin32 http://imagespark.net/files/old.png](http://imagespark.net/files/old.png)

Comment: of related interest: the new 'ttk' module provides almost-native themes for Windows vista/7 - http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ttk.html ... screenshots available at: http://tkdocs.com/tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: a resounding YES.

I know that this is possible because I have seen it being done before. but I am not entirely certain as to how it is done.

At the very least, you can use [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) and use Windows' builtin .NET framework by wielding clr.

If you are not interested in IronPython, then might you consider something along the lines of [easyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) or [TkInter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)?

Comment: I'd rather not use IronPython. Do you still know where you have seen it being done before?

Comment: Reshure, in that case you should use the `ttk` module. See http://tkdocs.com/tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a side-by-side manifest specifying a correct version of ComCtl32.dll to the Python interpreter. Fortunately there is no need to change the interpreter executable itself.

- Create a file named `python.exe.manifest` in the directory containing `python.exe`.
- Put the following contents in that file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
> <assembly 
>    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
>    manifestVersion="1.0">
>  <assemblyIdentity 
>     processorArchitecture="x86" 
>     version="5.1.0.0"
>     type="win32"
>     name="python.exe"/>
>  <description>Python</description>
>  <dependency>
>   <dependentAssembly>
>     <assemblyIdentity
>          type="win32"
>          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
>          version="6.0.0.0"
>          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
>          language="*"
>          processorArchitecture="x86"/>
>   </dependentAssembly>
>  </dependency>
> </assembly>
> ```

You may want to copy `python.exe.manifest` to `pythonw.exe.manifest` too.

Comment: If the script runs under PythonWin.exe, then probably the manifest should be PythonWin.exe.manifest.

Comment: I'm running from python.exe (ActivePython 3.1)

Comment: Maybe it needs to be for the Python dll? I do know that the manifest is the way to change this, so it might take some experimentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works even if we use py2exe. If we add the manifest in the dist folder created by py2exe, we will get the modern look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using '`winxpgui`' module instead of '`win32gui`' module?

I'm not sure if there's a '`winvistagui`' or '`win7gui`' module, but '`winxpgui`' does exist and may work, as it has a manifest included.